# Como usar a row selecionada do pickerView em outra lugar ou outra funcao no swift?

Tags: swift

**Aqui esta um trecho co pickerView implementado**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Implementacao do pickerview
    
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
    
    dados.append("MG")
    dados.append("BA")
    dados.append("RJ")
    dados.append("PR")
    dados.append("GO")
    dados.append("AM")
    dados.append("SP")
    
    
    carregarLogoNav()
    
    txtCPF.delegate = self
    txtNasc.delegate = self
    txtCelular.delegate = self
    txtTelefone.delegate = self
    
    verInfos()
    
    for field in arrayFields() {
        field.setFieldEstilos()
    }
}

//Metofos necessarios para que o pickerView do campo Estado funcione ABAIXO
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dados.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dados[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(dados[row])
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = (view as? UILabel) ?? UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = dados[row]
    return label
}
```

consigo retornar o valor da row selecionada mas nao consigo inserir ela no banco de dados! pq quando uso o dados[row] em outra função ela diz que esta fora do escopo!

```
func editaCad(){
    let pac = Paciente(
        nome: txtNome.text,
        sobrenome: txtSobreN.text,
        cpf: txtCPF.text,
        data_nascimento: txtNasc.text,
        sexo: sexo,
        celular: txtCelular.text,
        email: txtEmail.text,
        rg: txtRG.text,
        telefone: txtTelefone.text,
        endereco: txtEndereco.text,
        numero: txtNumero.text,
        complemento: txtCompl.text,
        bairro: txtBairro.text,
        nome_cidade: txtCidade.text,
        uf: txtEstado.text, ((((  Aqui onde quero guardar o retorno do pickerView   ))))
        cep: txtCEP.text,
        codigo_ibge_cidade: self.ibge)
    
    Requests.editarPac(paciente: pac) {response in
        if let _ = response.value?.success {
            self.mostraAlertaCall(titulo: Mensagens.SUCESSO, msg: Mensagens.CAD_EDT_SUCESSO) { clique in
                self.voltaUltimaView()
            }
        }
        if let resposta = response.value?.message {
            self.showAlerta(titulo: Mensagens.ERRO, msg: resposta)
        }
        if let erros = response.value?.errors {
            if let email = erros.email {
                self.showAlerta(titulo: Mensagens.ERRO, msg: email[0])
                self.txtEmail.setFieldErro()
            }
            if let cpf = erros.cpf {
                self.showAlerta(titulo: Mensagens.ERRO, msg: cpf[0])
                self.txtCPF.setFieldErro()
            }
            if let nasc = erros.data_nascimento {
                self.showAlerta(titulo: Mensagens.ERRO, msg: nasc[0])
                self.txtNasc.setFieldErro()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vc quer pegar o ID ou a descrição do item selecionado pelo pickerView?

Comment: eu tenho todas essas informações porem na hora de salvar no DB eu nao consigo usar a variavel emitida pela funcao, no caso a row selecionada em outras funcoes por exemplo, mas consegui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De maneira simples basta chamar o método `selectedRow` do pickerview onde o parâmetro `inComponent` especifica qual parte do pickerView será selecionada, como é um componente simples pode passar zero, `inComponent` seria o equivalente a section de uma tableView. O retorno do método é um `Int` que representa o item selecionado, agora basta passar ele para seu array algo como: `dados[selectedIndex]`

```
// obtém o índice selecionado
let selectedIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
 
// obtém a descrição do item
print(dados[selectedIndex])
```

Montei um um exemplo baseado storyboard com um pickerView, label e um botão. Foi adicionado o método `getSelectedItem()` que usa a lógica cita a cima para isolar essa parte do código e `didTap()` chama `getSelectedItem()` e atualizar o valor do label com a descrição selecionada do pickerView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    
    let items = ["MG", "BA", "RJ", "PR", "GO", "AM"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self  
    }

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        descriptionLabel.text = "Item Selecionado: \(getSelectedItem())"
    }
    
    private func getSelectedItem(component: Int = 0) -> String {
        let selectedIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component)
        return items[selectedIndex]
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return items[row]
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate { }
```

O resultado desse código é o gif abaixo:

[image: gif app]

Comment: Boa cara!! resolvi aqui!! muito obrigado